# Interpolation using LogNormal distributions in R

Tags: r, interpolation, distribution

I want to interpolate the dataset below using lognormal distribution in R. As you can see from the data below, I have different land size classes (ha) and I would like to interpolate the data using the standard land size classes I will use for all countries.

This is the original land size classes

| Size classes (ha) | Area of holdings |
| --- | --- |
| Under 0.8 ha | 18012 |
| 0.8 - 1.6 | 66155 |
| 1.6 - 2.4 | 80224 |
| 2.4 - 3.2 | 61555 |
| 3.2 - 4.0 | 47754 |
| 4.0 - 6.0 | 56234 |
| 6.0 ha and over | 38257 |
| Total holdings | 368191 |

And the standard land sizes which I want to interpolate their data using the data above are given as:

| size classes (ha) |
| --- |
| 0 - 1 |
| 1 - 2 |
| 2 - 3 |
| 3 - 4 |
| 4 - 5 |
| 5 - 10 |

I have performed this calculation in Excel and I would like to create an R function to do this.

The code below is the function I am trying to create.

```
install.packages("assertthat")
library(assertthat)
interpolation <- function(x, x1, y1,x2, y2) 
{
assert_that(is.numeric(x), 
isTRUE(all(is.finite(x))),
                       is.scalar(x1),
                      is.scalar(y1),
                      is.scalar(x2),
                     is.scalar(y2),
                    x1< x2)
meanlog <- mean(log(y2)
SDlog <- sd(log(y2)
output <- rep(NA_real_, length(x))
output[x <= x1] <- y1
output[x >= x2] <- y2
btwpoints <- which(is.na(output))
output[btwpoints] <- stats::approx(
    x = plnorm(c(x1, x2)),
   y = c(y1, y2),
  xoutput = plnorm(x[btwpoints]), method = 
"linear")$y
return(output)
}
```

I have succeeded in setting up the four coordinates (x1,x2,y1, y2) which represent the lower and upper size classes. I am stuck in setting up the lognormal distribution in the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ofcourse i know. I have added some table examples and code. Thanks.

Comment: My advice about how to approach this question is to first find the parameters of a lognormal distribution which has probability masses for the intervals stated in the problem data, and then calculate probability masses for the other intervals. Finding the parameters for a distribution given masses for intervals is a fairly common question, but there doesn't seem to be a standard way to solve it. Anyway, I think the question has been asked on Stackoverflow or stats.stackexchange.com. I will look for a link.

Comment: @RobertDodier could you help me with the link where a similar question was asked? I have derived the parameters of the lognormal distribution, trying to figure out how to derive the probability masses for other intervals. I will figure it out. Thanks

Comment: If you have the parameters, you can compute the numbers for the new intervals as (N times (cdf(x[i + 1]) minus cdf(x[i]))) where x[1], x[2], x[3], ... are the endpoints of the intervals (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, ... in this example) and cdf(...) is the cdf of the lognormal distribution for the given parameters. In R, the cdf is `plnorm`.) The closest question I know of (it's not a close match) is: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11176/can-anyone-explain-quantile-maximum-probability-estimation-qmpe and see my response there.